# Find the measure of a central angle of the circle. Arc length=1 ,Circumference=9

Tags: geometry

Really need help on this credit recovery computer class.

Comment: The question should be in the question body. Do not rely on the title alone. You should also explain what you have tried, because otherwise it is difficult to guess what kind of advice will actually help you. For example, what related problems have you done as examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the angle be $x$.

$S=rx$ so $x=\frac{S}{r}$

First find the radius:

$C=2\pi$ (radius)

$\text{radius}=\frac{C}{2\pi}$

$\text{radius}=\frac{9}{2\pi}$

So now plug in values:

$$x=\frac{1}{(\frac{9}{2\pi})}$$

$$x=\frac{2\pi}{9}$$

Comment: it also tell me to use pi or 3.14

Comment: So this would be an acceptable answer. If you want you could get a numerical answer you could just plug it in a calculator.